# Unable to launch docker container with custom seccomp profile

Tags: docker, containers, seccomp

Unable to initiate docker container with a custom seccomp profile using JSON. Getting below error.

```
sudo docker run --name=alpin1effcon1t -it 453135d09376 --security-opt seccomp:chrome.json
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "--security-opt": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

We have tried this on various docker platforms like Docker Desktop-WSL, Docker playgrounds and Amazon Linux based  EC2. Same error.

Docker info on EC2

```
grep SECCOMP /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_SECCOMP=y
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_SECCOMP_FILTER=y
CONFIG_SECCOMP=y
CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER=y

Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.10.75-79.358.amzn2.x86_64
 Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for `docker run` is:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

This means that after the image name/id you specify the command with the arguments you want to execute after the container starts. In other words you override the `CMD` specified in the `Dockerfile`.

In your example, you are telling docker to execute `--security-opt seccomp:chrome.json` at container startup. And `--security-opt seccomp:chrome.json` is not a proper linux command (It is not found in the dirs in `$PATH`.

With that said, what you should do is swap the order of `--security-opt` and the image id. Because `--security-opt` is a `docker run` option.

```
sudo docker run --name=alpin1effcon1t -it --security-opt seccomp:chrome.json 453135d09376
```